# Position shift in picture based on camera height

Tags: algorithm, image, math, image-processing, camera

I have a small problem, maybe someone here can help me out.

I use a camera to take measurements of a human dummy. The camera picture contains a rectangle in which the dummy should be positioned.

Determining the size of the rectangle is no problem, since the dummy size, the distance to the camera and the focal length are known. `( pixelsize = (size*focallength)/distance )`

**The problem** appears, when measuring with different camera heights. If the camera is placed higher, the dummy position in the picture goes down.
It seems that the previous mentioned formula cannot be used here, I am getting false results.

I tried to measure the differences for different camera heights and figured out that its changes are non linear.

So **my question** is, if there is a way or a formula to determine the shift of the dummy position in the picture based on the camera height.
I've already searched for solutions but didn't find anything specific.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could check for lens distortion by calculating and applying a homography matrix.  Outside of that, if you know your camera height and distance to target... everything should be pretty linear.

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear An homography is not caused by distortion but by normal perspective effect.

Comment: If your camera remains upright, the apparent size does not change. So presumably you tilt it, and the rectangle turns to a trapezoid. You must resort to perspective projection equations.

Comment: All perspective effects should be linear afaik, lens distortion is the only thing that would cause nonlinear issues

Comment: @Okayyo as Yves said, you will have to tilt the camera and get it much closer to the dummy, check out the figure in my answer below .

Answer (score 0):

[image: diagram]

as you see from the image above:

1. when you put the camera higher you need to tilt it in an angle (the **purple** angle) and get closer to fit the dummy inside the rectangle (the red rectangle)
2. in this case, when use your formula `( pixelsize = (size*focallength)/distance )` you will get the **orange** line length which will give a smaller value which is in correct, you need the **green** line length
3. you can get the **green** line length from the **orange** line length and the **purple** angle
4. to get the **purple** angle you can use the accelerometer if you are using mobile or get it manually since you are tilting the camera to fit the dummy inside the red rectangle.
5. so the formula is `orang line length / sin(purple angle) = green line length`

Or  `Green = Orange / sin(Purple)`

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but thanks a lot :)